# EMV chip reader/payment processor solution with REST API capabilities

Tags: rest, api, emv

I am looking to implement an EMV chip reader/payment processor solution with REST API capabilities and Card Verification Modes (CVMs): Chip-and-Signature for Credit Cards and Chip-and-PIN for Debit Cards.

Here is the process flow that I need:

1. Web Based POS sends transaction to the server.
2. Transaction information is saved (order number, product numbers, total, etc.). The server sends an API request to the EMV to start credit / debit card payment process. HTTP local network connection.
3. EMV receives API Request from the server via HTTP and start capturing payment process.
   Connects to the payment gateway to process payment. NOTE: EMV must have REST API capabilities.
4. The payment gateway processes the payment and sends the answer back to the EMV, which sends the answer back to the server to update the transaction record.
5. The server sends the answer to the host to finalize the transaction, depending on the answer received.

Has anyone implemented this type of solution before? If so, which solution (Square, Clover, etc.) was used?

Comment: You are asking for the "process flow," but then continue on to describe exactly that.  Are you developing your own solution?  Why do you mention Square & Clover (which also have similar process flows as you describe)?  Do you have an actual programming problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really belong to stackoverflow - it's not programming, you have not shown any code nor described what you are doing and what have you done so far.

What you describe is pretty generic description of the Retail ECR protocol. There are numerous variants and implementations, some may expose REST. Some may work with central server exposing REST API to POS, others will have a listening port on the EFT terminal side (there should normally be some firewall limitations on how many connections and what is the connection source, etc.). Almost any acquirer or PSP will have some implementation (however not necessarily with REST over HTTP), so you might want to start with your local service providers as they will probably best reflect your needs where it comes to acceptance methods, card schemes supported, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could have added a simple illustration to make the interactions clearer. EMV is a specification or a standard FYI.

In Step 2. Did you mean you have an  EMV certified terminal which exposes an API, which the server can call to initiate a transaction with card ? In that case HTTP connection is between the server and terminal, and the chip and terminal connection is direct. Correct ? This is do able.

Step 3. Now that the terminal has already communicated with card in APDUs and has at hand a cryptogram( ARQC, which require you to send the request to issuer for verification - Onilne ), you need to communicate with the acquirer. This communication is up to your implementation. You may do it via SOAP or REST or whatever.

Step 4. If an ARPC exists, this should be forwarded to card, which the card will validate and ensure the response is from right issuer. Otherwise it may send the acquirer a reversal( if the response was approved ). If ARPC is validated call host to update on the payment.

In any case if you are looking for a solution where the server will communicate with the card directly it most likely will not work as it will not be able to meet the acceptable timelines between the APDUs.

You have not told your problem yet. Are you trying to ascertain the feasibility of your proposed architecture ?